# markov chain is reversible if there is a unique stationary distribution?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, markov-chains, markov-process

I know that a reversible distribution is a stationary distribution, but is there a case where we have a stationary distribution but it's not reversible distribution? In other words, every stationary distribution is also reversible?
Why yes, why not?

Thanks.

Comment: Reversibility is a stronger condition. Consider 
$$
P = \pmatrix{0&1/3 &2/3 \\ 2/3&0&1/3 \\ 1/3 &2/3 &0},
$$
which is irreducible and aperiodic, and hence has a unique stationary distribution $\pi$ (which is uniform as $P$ is doubly stochastic). But
$$
\pi_0P_{01} = 1/3\cdot1/3=1/9
$$
while
$$
\pi_1P_{10}=1/3\cdot2/3 = 2/9,
$$
so the Markov chain is not reversible.

Comment: Thank you, good example, I want to accept your answer but it's a comment

Comment: No worries. You may be interested in the Kolmogorov criterion, which is a necessary and sufficient condition for a Markov chain to be reversible.