# A time-reversible Markov chain must be irreducable?

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, markov-chains

Consider a  (homogeneous) discrete-time Markov chain. We know that:

- If it is time-reversible, there exists an unique stationary distribution.
- if it is irreducible and positive recurrent, there exists an unique stationary distribution.

I also notice that [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2810999)  provides an example claiming an irreducable Markov chain is *not* always time-reversible.  I am just wandering that whether we can have the following conclusion:

> **A time-reversible Markov chain must be irreducible** !

The question arises that all examples of reversible Markov chains that I can find in the textbooks so far are irreducible.  It seems to imply that time-reversibility is stronger than irreducibility (I am not sure, just an impression), while curiously I can not find the corresponding definite proofs  in the books. If  the conclusion is right, the detailed proof or clues for book references are welcome. If the conclusion is wrong,  a reversible yet reducible counter-example is favored!  If  the conclusion is partially (conditionally) right, then what additional conditions should we add (finite Markov chain? ) ?